# Lucky prizes game infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I made a basic 'Lucky Prizes' game in Javascript and yet cannot work out how to stop it from infinitely looping. Is there anything I am obviously doing wrong as I am a beginner and the help would be appreciated.

```
var winNumber = 0;
var lossNumber = 0;

while (lossNumber < 10);
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (randomNumber > 20 && randomNumber < 40) {
        var winNumber = winNumber + 1;
    } else
    {
        var lossNumber = lossNumber + 1;
    }
}
console.log('Number of wins: ' + winNumber);
console.log('Number of losses: ' + lossNumber);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You redeclared the variables `winNumber` and `lossNumber` again.

Try this:

```
var winNumber = 0;
var lossNumber = 0;

while (lossNumber < 10)
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (randomNumber > 20 && randomNumber < 40) {
        winNumber = winNumber + 1;
    } 
    else {
        lossNumber = lossNumber + 1;
    }
}
console.log('Number of wins: ' + winNumber);
console.log('Number of losses: ' + lossNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your entire problem is due to an errant semicolon in `while (lossNumber < 10);`

This causes the rest of the condition to not be evaluated so the loop never ends. Using `var` again inside the loops isn't necessary but it's also not the cause of your problem, the semicolon is.

```js
var winNumber = 0;
var lossNumber = 0;

while (lossNumber < 10)
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (randomNumber > 20 && randomNumber < 40) {
        var winNumber = winNumber + 1;
    } else
    {
        var lossNumber = lossNumber + 1;
    }
}
console.log('Number of wins: ' + winNumber);
console.log('Number of losses: ' + lossNumber);
```